# Why is my program is not finding the getSelectedIndex() method that is trying to get a selection from a JComboBox?

Tags: java, jcombobox, itemlistener

My program is not finding the symbol getSelectedIndex() method. I wanted to know why it was not finding it and how to fix this. 
Here is the Error:
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getSelectedIndex()
  location: variable roomChoice of type java.lang.String[]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  

public class CottageRental2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
  // Declare all instance data  (primitives and objects used) 
  private int WIDTH = 676;
  private int HEIGHT = 321; 
  Container con; 
  private JLabel label1;
  private JLabel label2;
  private JLabel label3;
  JComboBox  cbox1;
  JComboBox cbox2;
  String [ ] roomChoice = {"1 Bedroom: $600","2 Bedroom: $800","3 Bedroom: $1000"};
 String [] activityChoice = {"Horse Back Riding: $60","Rafting: $40","Row Boat Rental:       $50"};
  ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Coding\\Desktop\\cottage.jpeg");
  Font f1 = new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 30);

//constructor 
  public CottageRental2(){
    super("Cottage Rental"); 
    con = getContentPane(); 
    con.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    con.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
}

  public void createGUI(){
    label1 = new JLabel("Woodberry Cottage Rental", JLabel.CENTER);
    label1.setFont(f1);
    label1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    label2 = new JLabel("Rental Amount Due: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    label2.setFont(f1);
    label2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    label3 = new JLabel(icon1);
    cbox1 = new JComboBox();
    cbox1.addItem(roomChoice);
    cbox2 = new JComboBox();
    cbox2.addItem(activityChoice);
    con.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    con.add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    con.add(label3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    con.add(cbox1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    con.add(cbox2, BorderLayout.EAST);
  }

  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if(source == roomChoice){
      int roomIndex = roomChoice.getSelectedIndex();
      if(roomIndex == 1){
        int price1 = 600;
      }
      if(roomIndex == 2){
        int price1 = 800;
      }
      if(roomIndex == 3){
        int price1 = 1000;
      }
    }
    if(source == activityChoice){
      int activityIndex = activityChoice.getSelectedIndex();
      if(activityIndex == 1){
        int price2 = 60;
      }
      if(activityIndex == 2){
        int price2 = 40;
      }
      if(activityIndex == 3){
        int price2 = 50;
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    CottageRental2 object = new CottageRental2(); 
    object.createGUI();
    object.setSize(675, 320);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not use == for testing object equality, use equals. The source will never be equal to roomChoice though, as it is not a JComboBox, but the alternatives, a String array. You should use the cbox1 or the cbox2 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `getSelectedIndex()` on a `String[]` (`roomChoice`), but arrays don't have a method by that name. So, it is telling you it can't find that method.

I believe you meant to do `cbox1.getSelectedIndex()`. The same applies for `activityChoice` and `cbox2`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I hope this may help someone else in the future